# javax.persistence.NamedQuery is not a repeatable annotation type

Tags: annotations, java-8

Normally in `Java` 8 the `@NamedQuery` is repeatable.

Nevertheless when I compile I have the error:

```
javax.persistence.NamedQuery is not a repeatable annotation type
```

Here is my source code:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "listDocumentsByStatus", query = "FROM Document d WHERE    d.status = :STATUS ")
@NamedQuery(name = "listDocumentsByNameAndType", query = "FROM Document d WHERE d.type = :TYPE AND UPPER(d.name) LIKE :NAME ")
public abstract class Document implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Do I misunderstood someething?

Comment: Define “normally”. An annotation is repeatable if it has the Java8-Annotation `@Repeatabe`. The official JavaEE7-version of `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` has not.

Comment: @Holger you were right I though `@NamedQuery` in JavaEE7 was repeatable as `@Repeatable` is implemented in Java8

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name = "findAllExtensionsSorted", query = "select e from Abc e order by e.c") 
@NamedQuery(name = "findByType", query = "select e from Abc e where e.t = :type"))
public class Abc...
```

Comment: I already used `@NamedQueries` but I wished to use repeatable annotation but not yet implemented in JavaEE7